# VBA Checkbox with 2 cells for reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have 4 different checkboxes with the same text "OTHER" but in different sections: Really Low, Low, Middle and High. I need the checkbox in the correct section to be checked if its reference cell has the value "Other" and the second reference cell has the value of its section (Really Low, Low, Middle and High).

Currently, I have the following VBA for just one cell reference that works correctly but now need to add another reference value.

`Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox48.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "ah") = "Other"`

Comment: Have you tried using `And` yet?

Comment: I have not. Would you be able to provide and example as I am new to VBA? Would I add And then put sheet and cell reference?

Comment: `Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox48.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "ah").Value = "Other" And Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "ai").Value = "Low"` for example.  It would help us out if you could show more of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim Williams' comment below answered my question.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox48.Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "ah").Value = "Other" And Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "ai").Value = "Low"
```